# Mongoose find results between 2 dates from html datepicker

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, datetime, mongoose

I have the following sub-documents :

```
{
 id: 1,
 date:2019-04-01 00:21:19.000
 },
{
 id: 2, 
 date:2019-03-31 00:21:19.000
} ...
Document schema is :
const barEventSchema = new Schema({
id: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    required: true
},
raw: { type: String },
date: { type: Date },
type: { type: String },

})

const FooSchema = new Schema({
   bar: [barEventSchema]
})
```

I want to do a query based on a date range picked from html input, which has values like `2019-04-01`, `2019-03-31`.
So on serverside, I want to do something like:

```
//@star_date = 2019-04-01, @end_date = 2019-04-01
Foo.findOne('bar.date' : {$lte : start_date, $gte: end_date})
```

However, this returns all the documents.

Comment: try as date `Foo.find(date : {$lte : new Date(start_date), $gte: new Date(end_date)}`

Comment: Still getting all the documents

Comment: Are your dates stored as strings or actual dates in mongo?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine, you mean `Foo.find({date : {$gte : new Date(start_date), $lte: new Date(end_date)}})` to get documents with date between start date and end date

Comment: Updated question with schema used. start_date would be the newest date and end_date oldest date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All documents having any subdocument with date between start and end date range can be retrieved using:

```
const conditions = {
  'bar': {
    $elemMatch: {
      'date': {
        $gte: new Date(start_date), 
        $lte: new Date(end_date)
      }
    }
  }
}

Foo.find(conditions)
```

This will return all the documents where there is at least a subdocument having its date between the range specified in `condition`.
The [`$elemMatch` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) is used to effect this condition on the `date` field of the bar subdocument.

Comment: I only need to retrieve a single document and only the sub-documents that are between the date range.

Comment: No, you can't do that exactly in Mongo. What you can do is unwind the nested subdocuments in an aggregation and filter only ones where dates are within the given date range.